# MVC reusable search window

Tags: model-view-controller

In mvc how to create customer search page. Also how to call invoke this as modal popup from other views button (need to call in different views). How to pass the customerid and customername after searching to the page invoking the search page. Requirement is reusable customer search window.
Tried with bootstrap modal popup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a partial view `_PartialSearch.cshtml` and include it in your `_Layout.cshtml` file:

`@Html.Partial("_PartialSearch")`

The partial view will call the `Search` method in your controller and get the search results.

**Views/Shared/_PartialSearch.cshtml**

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Search window</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <input type="search" id="searchString"><button type="submit" id="search">Search</button>
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div id="result"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

@{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            //Init the result
            $("#result").load("@Url.Action("GetAll", "Home")");

            $("#search").click(function() {
                var searchString = $("#searchString").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "@Url.Action("Search", "Home")",
                    data: '{searchString: "' + searchString + '" }',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "html",
                    success: function(response) {
                        $('#result').html(response);
                    },
                    failure: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function(response) {
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

**Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                @Html.ActionLink("Application name", "Index", "Home", new { area = "" }, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Another Page", "AnotherPage", "Home")</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>


    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)

    @Html.Partial("_PartialSearch")
</body>
</html>
```

2. Create a `Customer` model to store your customer's data

**Models/Customer.cs**

```
namespace SearchModal.Models
{
    public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

3. Create a `Movie` model to store your search data

**Models/Movie.cs**

```
namespace SearchModal.Models
{
    public class Movie
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

4. Create a `SearchResultVm` viewmodel to store your view data

**Viewmodels/SearchResultVm.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using SearchModal.Models;

namespace SearchModal.ViewModels
{
    public class SearchResultVm
    {
        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

5. Create a `SessionDataManager` manager to manage your `Customer` session

**Managers/SessionDataManager.cs**

```
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;
using SearchModal.Models;

namespace SearchModal.Managers
{
    public class SessionDataManager : ISessionDataManager
    {
        private HttpSessionState CurrentSession => HttpContext.Current?.Session;

        private object GetSessionObject(string key, bool redirectToSessionEnd = true)
        {
            var obj = CurrentSession?[key];
            if (obj == null)
            {
                //no session
            }
            return obj;
        }

        private void SetSessionObject<T>(string sessionObjectName, T value)
        {
            CurrentSession[sessionObjectName] = value;
        }

        public Customer Customer
        {
            get => GetSessionObject("Customer") as Customer;
            set => SetSessionObject("Customer", value);
        }

    }

    public interface ISessionDataManager
    {
        Customer Customer { get; set; }
    }
}
```

6. Create a `HomeController` controller to handle your different views that has the search button (i.e. `Index` and `AnotherPage`)
7. Create a `Search` method to handle your search request and return a partial view with the results

**Controllers/HomeController.cs**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using SearchModal.Managers;
using SearchModal.Models;
using SearchModal.ViewModels;

namespace SearchModal.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private ISessionDataManager _sessionDataManager;
        private List<Movie> _movies;
        public HomeController()
        {
            //TODO Inject through Dependency Injection
            _sessionDataManager = new SessionDataManager();
            _movies = new List<Movie>
            {
                new Movie
                {
                    Id = 1, Name="Die Hard", Description = "Christmas movie"
                },
                new Movie
                {
                    Id = 2, Name="Armageddon", Description = "End of the world"
                },
                new Movie
                {
                    Id = 3, Name="Love actually", Description = "Chick flick"
                }

            };
        }
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //Set customer details
            var customer = new Customer {Id = 1, Name = "Bob"};
            _sessionDataManager.Customer = customer;

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult AnotherPage()
        {
            //Get customer info
            var customer = _sessionDataManager.Customer as Customer;
            //Do something with customer info

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetAll()
        {
            //Get customer info
            var customer = _sessionDataManager.Customer as Customer;
            //Do something with customer info

            var viewModel = new SearchResultVm
            {
                Movies = _movies
            };
            return PartialView("_SearchResult", viewModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Search(string searchString)
        {
            //Get customer info
            var customer = _sessionDataManager.Customer as Customer;
            //Do something with customer info

            var viewModel = new SearchResultVm
            {
                Movies = _movies.Where(m => m.Name.Contains(searchString)).ToList()
            };
            return PartialView("_SearchResult", viewModel);
        }
    }
}
```

8. Create an `Index` view to show your search button. The only line you need to include in other views are this:

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>`

**Views/Home/Index.cshtml**

```
<div>
    <h1>Index</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

9. Create an `AnotherPage` view for another page with the search button

**Views/Home/AnotherPage.cshtml**

```
<div>
    <h1>Another Page</h1>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>
</div>
```

10. Create a `_SearchResult` partial view to show results

**Views/Home/_SearchResult.cshtml**

```
@model SearchModal.ViewModels.SearchResultVm

<br/>
<b>Results: </b><br/>
@foreach (var movie in Model.Movies)
{
    <b>@movie.Name</b> @:- @movie.Description<br />
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: i checked the modal page link. Per this Modal div layout (myModal) has to be present in all views where search functionality is there. this repetition can be avoided?

Comment: that is the Modal and button to trigger the modal is in same page. we want to trigger modal on search page

Comment: Put the modal code in the ```_Layout ``` file or in a partial view.

Comment: how to pass data(model) for search window. can you explain the complete flow step by step

Comment: @Bala See my edit.

Comment: is there any repetation of search code

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: can i move the search code also common

Comment: In the Search method in HomeController? Or which file do you mean? The code in the Homecontroller.Search() method can be moved to a [Service/Repository](https://exceptionnotfound.net/the-repository-service-pattern-with-dependency-injection-and-asp-net-core/) for example.

Comment: when search page opens it should show all movies. after entering movie name and search it should filter and show. currently second is happening. how to make first also to happen

Comment: @Bala See my edit. I added a ```GetAll()``` method to the ```HomeController.cs``` and then call that in the ```_PartialSearch.cshtml```

Comment: you saved lot of efforts. will check and ask more questions

Comment: After searching, Is Search.cshtml rendered inside PartialSearch.cshtml

Comment: Yes ```Search.cshtml``` will do a for loop of the ```SearchVm.Movies``` property and render it as HTML in the ```<div id="result"></div>``` in ```_PartialSearch.cshtml```

Comment: suppose there are two textboxes in home index & anotherpage, searching for Love gives the result as Love actually - Chick flick.  want to set this result(s) in the textboxes.

Comment: Move the ```<div id="result"></div>``` to ```Index.cshtml``` and ```AnotherPage.cshtml```.

Comment: I am thinking autocomplete for searching. can we have multi columns in autocomplete.

Comment: Please search on Stackoverflow or Google for any further questions.